# How do I add product ratings to a collection?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have the following code to allow me to show products with a "featured" attribute, on the front page of my store.

```
$_productCollection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->joinField('value','catalog_product_entity_tier_price','value', 'entity_id=entity_id','{{table}}.website_id='.$storeId, 'left')
        ->setPageSize(9)
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId);
```

The issue is, I need to be able to show the product ratings ($this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') in my normal category listing)

How can I add the data into the collection to allow me to use:

```
if($_product->getRatingSummary()):
    echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short')
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in your collection loop:

```
Mage::helper('review/product')->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true);
```

Your loop should look something like:

```
foreach($_productCollection as $_product)
{
    echo Mage::helper('review/product')->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true);
}
```

Comment: it's fatal error `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Review_Helper_Product' not found`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, in product collection

```
$reviewHelper = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/helper');
echo $reviewHelper->getSummaryHtml($_product, 'short', false);
```

[Reference Here](http://developersushant.blogspot.com/2015/01/magento-show-product-rating-in-custom.html)